# Include tags or groups in Advanced search views?

Tags: search-results

Is it possible to display a contact's tags in an advanced search listing? I was hoping to make a 'Search Views' profile including the tags field and then have this column show up in the results of an advanced search.

However, when I go to make a tag field in the profile, the option to choose 'results column' disappears as soon as I choose Contacts > Tags.

I guess that's to stop multiple tags from clogging up the search display results. But I want to see those multiple tags...

I've tested this in civicrm demo 4.6. And have the same in our system; we're using 4.6.24 and Drupal 7.54.

So is there a way to make this happen?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Advanced Search - I don't think that is possible now due to the reason mentioned in the question. But it could be fixed by filing a JIRA/PR etc.

Workaround - Use Search Builder and fire a query for tags not null. Similar to -

[image]

Hitting Search would display multiple tags in search results.

Comment: This is a handy solution; thanks Jitendra. In fact, this works more broadly. It seems that every row in the search builder creates a column, whatever its data - at least with limited testing. So you can have an output with Tags, Groups and any other fields in the search builder. These columns show all the values of multi-value fields. Perfect! Also, this applies to any search criteria for tags and groups, not just 'Not Null' as shown above.