# Displaying Tags as search result

Tags: search, search-results, tags

Trying to get all assigned tags displayed for my contacts when doing a quick search / using search builder or advanced search.

When adding tags through a profile, it seems they don't get displayed in the search results when using the same profile to detemrine the result structure. In another Post ([Include tags or groups in Advanced search views?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17990/include-tags-or-groups-in-advanced-search-views)) it seems one of the community members was able to resolve this using the search builder, trying to do that it seems the behaviour changed wheras the tags would not be displayed in the result.

Running CiviCRM 4.20 on Joomla.

Thanks,